# Secure boot / UEFI Boot issues after 15.04 installed

Tags: partitioning, usb, uefi, live-cd, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 (2015) with Win 8.1 Pro installed. I created a UEFI USB boot drive with Ubuntu 15.04 on it. Using Windows I shrank my windows partition by 40GB. I inserted the USB and rebooted,  chose the appropriate boot media from the boot menu and installed Ubuntu no issues.

The problem is that I now want to expand the linux partition. I have freed up more space from windows but I have hit a wall. I cannot boot from the USB any more, its like the EFI is seeing that it has an Ubuntu entry and wont allow me to boot it from USB. I have tried recreating the UEFI boot USB and tried a different USB drive. Both USB drives pass tests fine and work in windows or ubuntu.

My bios is in its default config with Secure Boot ON and UEFI only.  The Bios shows under boot 
1) Ubuntu
2) Windows
3) Liteon M2 SSD

I can add a 4th option manually. I have attempted to point it to the UBS drive /EFI/Boot/Grub64.efi  but this fails to load.

Any suggestions tips?? I am happy to wipe the ubuntu partition and start again as I currently have no data in that partition. I would like to leave windows and secure boot alone.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about Dell specifically, but most secure boot systems require another setting to allow USB boot. Often better to turn secure boot off. But you may still need setting on USB ports to allow them as bootable. USB UEFI drives boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Often have to copy  shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/ and rename to bootx64.efi. Make backup of the bootx64.efi as it is either another fallback boot loader or copy of Windows efi boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

Some EFIs can be flaky and lose functionality, such as the ability to launch their built-in boot managers, for no apparent reason. My guess is you've run into this problem.

One approach you might take is to fix the firmware's problem. I don't know of a sure-fire procedure for doing this, though, so you'll have to either find help elsewhere (maybe somebody else will post a specific procedure) or fumble around randomly, which is always a bit risky. You might try updating your firmware, entering the firmware setup utility and resetting it to its defaults, or deleting unused boot entries with `efibootmgr`. None of these approaches is entirely risk-free, though. The first two, in particular, run the risk of wiping out your Ubuntu boot entry.

Another thing you might try is installing my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) I recommend either the PPA or Debian package installation, both of which should set it all up optimally with no user intervention. If the installation is successful, when you reboot into rEFInd, it will scan for available boot loaders, without relying on NVRAM entries, so your USB drive should appear as an option. If you boot rEFInd and *don't* see your USB drive, try hitting the Esc key, which causes a re-scan. (Sometimes external devices don't appear immediately.) The risk to this approach is that installing a new boot program might exacerbate whatever firmware bug is causing your problems, so you might end up with some worse problems.

Overall, using `efibootmgr` to delete unused boot entries is probably the safest approach. (Type `sudo efibootmgr` alone to see what you've got, then use `sudo efibootmgr -b #### -B` to delete `Boot####` -- change `####` to the appropriate hexadecimal number. Delete only obvious duplicates or entries you're clearly not using, like network-boot options, at least initially.) If that doesn't help, installing rEFInd is the next-safest approach, followed by updating the firmware and/or resetting its defaults.

Comment: That's great thanks for the tips.  Luckily I solved it by changing the manual settings on the efi usb boot option I created in the bios.  I needed to launch bootx64.efi rather than the grub one.